# Why some API documents specifiy form data value types or content header value types?

Tags: http

This confused me so much today. Though I've got some ideas after doing some study, I would like to get some opinions here.

So here's one of the confusing API documents I've encoutered: https://console.faceplusplus.com.cn/documents/4888373. No need to read it carefully, I got confused when I saw this line:

```
 Request Parameter
          |     Name        | Type | Description
 Optional | return_landmark | Int | Whether or not detect and return key points of facial features and contour.  ...
```

How could there be a `Int` type in post body?

Another example I saw is:

```
parameter name | type | required | description
X-TC-Timestamp | Integer | Yes |Current UNIX timestamp to record the time an API request was made.For example, 1529223702.Note: if you miss the server time by more than 5 minutes, you will cause a signature expiration error.
```

And it's a custom content header required by the API. content header value, `Integer`?

Then I saw some demo code use it as a string...

```
curl -X POST https://somehost \
-H "Authorization: blablabla" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-H "Host: somehost" \
-H "X-TC-Action: DescribeInstances" \
-H "X-TC-Timestamp: 1551113065" \
-H "X-TC-Version: 2017-03-12" \
-d '{"Limit": 1, "Filters": [{"Values": ["\u672a\u547d\u540d"], "Name": "instance-name"}]}'
```